# codeigniter segment method

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, segment

Im newbie here.I have a problem with codeigniter segment() method.I referred  6th segment of URL at href($this->url->segment(6)) but when i click the link it goes to full URl/6th segment.i.e
I want my link will be go here www.webcoachbd.com(this is 6th segment of my URL)
but it goes http://www.example.com/controller_name/method_name/segment1/segment2/segment3/www.webcoachbd.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the resulting URL that you posted, it looks like you might be missing a forward slash.

```
<a href="/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(6); ?>">link text</a>
```

This would force the URL to forward to the root of your site, rather than to that location inside the current folder that the browser thinks it is in.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this in your view?

I dont know if $this->uri->segment will work inside views, never needed it myself.

Instead grab the URI inside your controller and pass it back to the view.

```
$this->load->view('some view', array(
    'link'    => $this->uri->segment(6)
));
```

-

```
<a href="<?php echo $link;?>">link</a>
```

Although I dont really understand why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Its not url but uri

```
$this->uri->segment(6);
```

and i think you are missing = operator in the anchor

```
<a href="<?=$this->uri->segment(6)?>">MyLink</a>
```